# Problem with Interface Builder and Xcode

Tags: objective-c, interface, console

From some reason, any time I connect IBOutlets or IBActions in Interface Builder, and build my app, the app crashes.
In the Console Log I get this:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key leftWebView.'

How can I solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have removed a property from your controller that is still hooked up to an Action or Outlet in Interface Builder. Try editing the view in Interface Builder to remove that connection.

Also check to see if the Class Identity on the nib is set to the name of the controller class that uses it.

Comment: Thanks, but it isn't the reason.
All of my outlets and actions are overlaping

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer with another suggestion. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Thanks, but what I say is that nothing is connected in INterface Builder and when I connect an outlet for example and build my app in the simulator is crashed

Comment: Nothing, I checked everything and nothing
Any attempt to make outlet/action connection ends with crash